# Django don't display default value in form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a large django form where most of the options have the same default value.
When a user goes to enter the form they have to remove the default value before they can enter their information.

[image]

I figured I could solve the issue by adding a place holder

```
    widgets = {
    'form_item': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'OEM'})
}
```

Now when I load the form it still has the default value text entered but if you remove it the place holder text is showen.

How do I not display the default value text in a form field

Comment: Does your models or (assuming your using modelForms) have defaults?

Comment: yes  `block = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="OEM") `

Comment: You need to remove it. It sounds like you dont actually want a default

Comment: If the user does not enter something I want a the default value I just don't want to have the text in the field for it. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be removing the defaults you have set in your models.

Then setting required attribute to `False` in `forms.py`.

```
   widgets = {
    'form_item': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': False})
}
```

and in your forms, when cleaning do something like

```
def clean_<field_name>(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data[<field_name>]
    if not value:
       return 'OEM'
    ...whatever other cleaning you want
    return value
```

If Django does interpet the empty string as valid(skips the if block), then just do

```
if value == '':
    ...run logic
```